# Alguien sabe como enviar mensaje por whatsapp mediante PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, me encuentro en un problema que vengo ya varios dias buscando, si se puede enviar mensaje por whatsapp mediante PHP, no se si exista una clase php para ello, algo lei con una API no oficial de Whatsapp, pero no logro hacer funcionar, pues me pide un password, etc.

Comment: Whatsapp no dispone de API oficial, es decir que de forma legitima eso no es posible.

Comment: La contrase;a seria:
"El nombre de usuario no es más que el número de teléfono y la clave es el MD5 del IMEI invertido (puesto al revés) del teléfono." > Fuente:
> https://bandaancha.eu/foros/tu-contrasena-whatsapp-tu-imei-1697483

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque al día de hoy WA ya no da más soporte sobre el uso de su API, quedando obsoleto desde 2016.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar esta API de Whatsapp. Tienes + información en Github (https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API) no es oficial pero la están usando muchos desarrolladores. Te dejo un tutorial completo de como hacer lo que quieres. (http://www.17educations.com/whatsapp/send-whatsapp-message-using-php/) En inglés.
Espero te sea de ayuda.